# Aggregating a lot of columns in R

Tags: r

I have a csv file containings a matrix:

```
version getSize() length() ... power
0         23000    23421        0.8
0           ..      ..           ..
1           ..      ..           ..
1           ..      ..           ..
```

I want to aggregate by similar versions applying the mean function to the columns. The columns are too many to write them. I need a way to specify all these columns.

Thanks in advance

Comment: look into `?colMeans`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `aggregate`. If your data.frame is called `df`, try:

```
newdf <- aggregate(. ~ version, data = df, mean)
```

Comment: What is the type of newdf? I'm trying to make a correlation plot but when I type this command `corMatrix <- cor(newdf, method="spearman")` it throws an error: `no applicable method for 'levelplot' applied to an object of class "data.frame"`

Comment: `newdf` is a data.frame. Type `?data.frame` for more info. It would be easier to help you if you provide more information on your actual data, e.g. by adding the ouput of `dput(head(youroriginaldata))` to your question.

Comment: The table is too big and the console cut the output. The table is pretty simple: the first column contains the version number and the last one contains power misurement for those versions. Between these columns there are 1700 columns, one for each method, containing the calls of that method in that version. An example is contained in the asked question above. Actually I'm using `lattice` library to plot the correlation.

Comment: what is the class of your object? And what exactly do you want to do then? Perhaps it makes more sense to ask another question than to explain everything here in the comments of a different question.

Comment: Yes I will post another question. Thanks a lot for your help!